# PHP Upgrading Worthwhile ... or not? PHP5.2.3 >> PHP5.2.17

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

From the following specific viewpoints, is it necessary to upgrade from *`5.2.3`* >> *`5.2.17`* or not?
Some more background info that may help with my specificness of this question:

What I DO care about/need best improvements:

- **GD image manipulation**
- **Speed of Load**

What I DONT need improvements in:

- site security
- Database usage/SQL etc

Comment: The PHP 5.2 branch has reached end of lifecycle and support. [You are encouraged to update to PHP 5.3.](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the PHP Changelog [here](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php).

At first glance I don't find speed improvements between 5.2.3 and 5.2.17, but there are a few bug fixes regarding specific GDLib functions which might affect the things you're coding.

I'd recommend to upgrade to 5.3 anyway because of the other issues you don't need improvement in! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

5.2 is EOL already. Consider upgrading to 5.3.6 now.